# Want to create mysql user in installation with full Privileges In NSIS

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-installer, nsis

I am using following code but did not succeed, please help

```
!define deflogin root
!define defpassword mysqlpassword
!define HOSTPORT "%"


ExecWait '$folder\bin\mysql --user=${deflogin} --password=${defpassword} --execute="grant all privileges on *.* to $\'${login}$\' @ $\'${HOSTPORT}$\' identified by $\'${password}$\'"'
```

`${login}` & `${password}` taken by a custom .ini configuration by following process

```
Function .onInit 
   InitPluginsDir
   !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_EXTRACT "database_details.ini"    
   !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_WRITE "database_details.ini" "Field 2" "State" "${login}"
   !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_WRITE "database_details.ini" "Field 4" "State" "${password}"
  FunctionEnd

  ReadINIStr $login "$PLUGINSDIR\database_details.ini" "Field 2" "State"
  ReadINIStr $password "$PLUGINSDIR\database_details.ini" "Field 4" "State"
```

Please tell where i am wrong.

Comment: "did not succeeded" is not very clear, can you tell what you get (error message, unexpected behavior) and what you expect?

Comment: After the above execution of code that account must be created but it not create any account  with given query in code   -->
        grant all privileges on *.* to $\'${login}$\' @ $\'${HOSTPORT}$\' identified by $\'${password}$\'"

Comment: @Seki Please tell where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Seki for your reply. This code is working fine i  am confuse between ${password} and $password and ${login} and $login thats why its not woking now i am correct that code and it works.

```
 ExecWait '$folder\bin\mysql --user=${deflogin} --password=${defpassword} --execute="grant all privileges on *.* to $\'$login$\' @ $\'${HOSTPORT}$\' identified by $\'$password$\'"'
```